# Bingo machine probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Bingo machine displays the number $k\in\{1, 2, 3\dots\}$, with probability $p_k=1/2^k$. If it displays an even number, the player loses a dollar, but if it displays an odd number, the player wins a dollar. Find the probability that after 1000 games, the player will have won between 100 and 200 dollars.

I guess this is the normal distribution and I understand that I am missing $p$. I have tried to find it, but it has led me nowhere.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So the probability that he wins a dollar is $\sum p_{2k+1} = \sum 2^{-2k-1} = 2/3$ and $\sum p_{2k} = \sum 2^{-2k} = 1/3$ that he looses...

Comment: If you want to use normal distribution the expected value of the distribution of the result after $1000$ games will be $1000$ times the expected value for one game and the variance is $1000$ times the variance for one game. The variance and expected can be calculated from the probability that one wins or loses one dollar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player loses a dollar with probability $\frac13$ and wins a dollar with probability $\frac23$. After 1000 games, winning between 100 and 200 dollars is equivalent to winning 550 and 600 games, so the desired probability is
$$\mathrm P(550\le B(1000,\tfrac23)\le600)$$
which, when evaluated directly, yields the answer $5.988×10^{-6}$. This is a tiny, tiny probability – the player's expected winnings are $\frac{1000}3=333.333\dots$ dollars, so whoever set the payout probably wasn't paying attention!